# Access Google credentials from Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview, firebase, inappbrowser

What I want to do is log my users in via Google in my mobile app powered by Phonegap on Android.

To do so I use firebase SimpleLogin module which logs me in correctly thanks to the "InAppBrowser" plugin.

My problem is that the webview powered by the InAppBrowser does not have access to my Google credentials. I have to tap them manually each time.

Is there a way to tell the webview how to automatically get my Google credentials from my phone so that I don't have to write them each time ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is pretty broad. Can you add more detail about what you've tried? I posted the best answer I could given the limited information in the question.

Comment: Your answer was pretty clear. I was looking at building a plugin using [GoogleAuthUtil](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html) to get an auth token and send it to my InAppBrowser. But I am not sure how to do that, and if that is doable...

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. If you're only using the browser for auth, consider using [Google+ Sign-in for Android](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) instead.

The browser on Android, like web browsers in general, runs in a sandbox. This means it does not have access to system resources such as [Android's AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html). This is done on purpose for security reasons.

Comment: So you're telling me there is no way to access the AccountManager through my InAppBrowser ?
If I use oAuth in Chrome, it automatically detects that I am logged in on my Google account and doen't ask for my credentials. It just displays the pop up to accept / decline the authentication process.

Comment: There are ways, but they're all indirect. It's one of the challenges in developing with platforms like Cordova. They work best all or nothing. Either your app is all in the Cordova container, or you might as well just write for Android directly.